# Media Queries - force xbox to use landscape view

Tags: media-queries, user-agent

I'm working on a website, when you view it on the Xbox, it uses the ipad site. Which it's good. But it's using the portrait mode, resulting in a huge waste of space on the side. I would like it to use landscape mode instead.

Is there a way of doing that? My guess would be with media queries, but I can't find anything.

Right now that's what I have:

```
if (preg_match('/(XBox|MSIE.* Touch|WiiU|MZ617|GT-N)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
   ...          
}
```